# JPanel is not updating one of the two pieces of data I need to be updated

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to track all of the supplies stored in a knapsack object and create an interface that shows the supplies update using an observer/observable implementation. For some reason when I run this code, with 2 items in the knapsack, the second item updates and shows expiration date decreasing as time change is triggered. The first one does not change at all, as if it's a static label. Please could someone let me know what I did wrong? Thanks so much for your help in advance! Also, I'm super new to Java programming so please extra information/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```html
package view;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import supplies.Supplies;
import model.Adventure;
import model.Knapsack;

public class InventoryView extends JPanel implements Observer{
 private Knapsack knapsack;
 private Adventure adventure;
 private JLabel b;

 public InventoryView(Adventure adventure) {
  this.adventure=adventure;
  this.knapsack=adventure.getSquad().getKnapsack();
  for (Supplies supply : knapsack.getSupplies()) {
   b=new JLabel(supply.toString());
   add(b);
  }
  knapsack.addObserver(this);
 }
 @Override
 public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    for (Supplies supply : knapsack.getSupplies()) {
     b.setText(supply.toString());
     add(b);
    }    
   }
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing is lazy when it comes to container updates (add/removes), this allows you to execute a number of add/removes in quick succession without fear that the system will grind to a halt while it attempts to update the entire container hierarchy on each call.

Call `revalidate` and `repaint` after you have added all your components.  Also, make sure that your `JPanel` is using a layout manager capable of supporting multiple children.

You might consider using a `JList` or `JTable` instead